# Multiple regexp_replace in single PL/SQL query, Replace Alphas with 'A', Numerals with '1'

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I need a single PL/SQL query that replaces alpha characters with an 'A' and replaces numeric characters with a '1'.

For example, if I had a list of UK registration plates:

- YA11 ABC
- AB10 EPC
- CD11 ABC

I would end up with a distinct list

- AA11 AAA

I can run the queries in isolation:

```
select distinct regexp_replace(FIELDNAME, '[A-Z]', 'A') 
from TABLE1;

select distinct regexp_replace(FIELDNAME, '[0-9]', '1') 
from TABLE1;
```

I know some genius on SO will know how to achieve this in a single query :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could easily combine it:

```
select distinct regexp_replace(regexp_replace(FIELDNAME, '[0-9]', '1'),
                '[A-Z]', 'A') as result
from (SELECT 'AB10 EPC' AS FIELDNAME FROM dual) s;
```

**[Rextester demo](http://rextester.com/NVNOQ43432)**

Comment: Thanks @lad2025, it worked perfectly with a minor mod in the 'FROM' my end.
select distinct
regexp_replace(regexp_replace(FIELDNAME, '[0-9]', '1'), '[A-Z]', 'A') as result
from TABLE1 s

Comment: @GoodJuJu He's just using `DUAL` so he can make a standalone example that works in any database.